Alternative to 'arp -a' for discovering local network devices communicated with
The arp command requires installation of additional packages on (Ubuntu) Linux.
Is there an alternative to it for discovering network devices available out of the box?
The equivalent would be arp -a.

Try ip neigh -show "The ip neigh command manipulates neighbour objects that establish bindings between
protocol addresses and link layer addresses for hosts sharing the same link.  Neighbour
entries are organized into tables. The IPv4 neighbour table is also known by another name
- the ARP table."

ARP isn't for "discovering network devices". It'll only have devices your PC talked to. Depending on your exact use case, I suggest looking for a different method.

Thanks a lot. ip neigh show (without dash) does what I was looking for!

nmap Command:
While nmap is not installed by default, it is a powerful tool for network discovery and can be easily installed. You can use it to scan your network and list all connected devices.

Consider changing to "discovering devices communicated with" (i.e. communicated with)

Thanks for the comment on nmap which is a classic program. My difficulty with it was that it was always somewhat slow, but I haven't tried in a while and never took a closer look at it.

nmap is slow if it's told to probe various ports (and especially so if the hosts have a 'drop by default' firewall), but you can tell it to do a "ping scan" that's much faster – and since you're dealing with your local subnet, you can specify the "ARP scan" mode which might be even faster, as well as detecting hosts that do not reply to regular ICMP pings. (There are dedicated ARP-scan tools as well.)
